# how to retrieve Data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table in SQLite database with following statement.

i.e.

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
"create table " + "TEST" + 
"( " + "ID" + " integer primary key autoincrement," + 
" UID text, FULLNAME text, GENDER integer, MSTATUS integer, MOBILE text, AGE text );";
```

with this statement, I can able to insert data but I want to design a function that will accept the mobile no. and return the UID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```java
String getUidEntry(String mobile)
{
    Cursor c = db.query("TEST", new String[] { "UID" },
                        "MOBILE = ?", new String[] { mobile },
                        null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
        return c.getString(0);
    else
        return ""; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proper select statement, I don't see why not the one provided by Bjorn and you can use this function to control it better.

```
<?php 
function sqlite_query_multi ($db, $query) { 

    $pattern = '/^(.*;)(.*;)/s';
    if ( preg_match($pattern,$query,$match) ) { 
     // multi-statement query
        sqlite_exec($db,$match[1]);
        $result = sqlite_query($db,$match[2]);
    } else { 
     // single-statement query
        $result = sqlite_query($db,$query);
    }
    return (@$result);
}
?>
```

You just need to feed the database parameter and also the query which can be a select statement providing the number and asking for the UID and then use the return as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to design a method in android application which will take the mobile no. as parameter and return the uid to the caller. Kindly provide the full method..

Comment: @Rajesh Your question did not denote that you were making an inquiry relating to Android and while I am familiar enough to create roots and patches for Android and assist in development, my focus is mainly on security, so I am not able to assist you there. The portion relating to `sqlite` is still valid and could be useful to you but I will defer to someone who knows more about Android's hook into the calling system and the people directory to answer your question further.

Answer (score 0):

A basic select statement should work

"Select UID from TEST where MOBILE = " + MoibileNr

im not realy used to sqlite so there might be some errors in the query but try it, and see if it works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It may run but I want to design a method. Can you provide the entire method.

Comment: Then you will have to provide more information, what language are u using? (maybee it is java due to the "static final" keywords), which api are you using and hwo do you do calls(create/insert) to the database at the moment

Comment: It is an android application (using eclipse), API level 17. I want to call that function by the following way.. String uid = TestDataBaseAdapter.getUidEntry(mobile); where TestDataBaseAdapter is the class name.

Comment: @Rajesh In the future if you include `android` in your tag or mention is somewhere in your question, it would become clear sooner that your focus is not just on sqlite but how it relates to a framework and SDK that might handle it differently.

@BjörnMårtensson He did not make it clear that `android` was involved, so I have to pull out of any further assistance too.